# Instance validation error calling web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm getting an instance validation error in my proxy class i use to call a web service. This proxy class was auto-generated by XSD2Code. To me the error doesn't match the code it's pointing to.

Exception Details:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Instance validation error:
>   'LessThanOrEqualTo' is not a valid
>   value for ComparisonOperatorType.

Source Error:

```
Line 12866:    cswgetCapabilitiesResponse csw.cswgetCapabilities(cswgetCapabilitiesRequest request)
Line 12867:    {
Line 12868:        return base.Channel.cswgetCapabilities(request);
Line 12869:    }
Line 12870:
```

Source File:

> d:\webapp\App_Code\ogc.csw.proxy.cs
>   Line: 12868

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Instance validation error: 'LessThanOrEqualTo' is not a valid value for ComparisonOperatorType.]
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReadercsw.Read156_ComparisonOperatorType(String s) +582
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReadercsw.Read157_ComparisonOperatorsType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) +742
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReadercsw.Read162_Scalar_CapabilitiesType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) +746
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReadercsw.Read165_Filter_Capabilities(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) +746
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReadercsw.Read166_CapabilitiesType(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) +1430
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReadercsw.Read280_Item() +281
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer11.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader) +43
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) +579

[InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (284, 13).]
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) +1375
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle) +163
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) +606

[CommunicationException: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'cswgetCapabilities'.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +4767763
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +1725
   csw.cswgetCapabilities(cswgetCapabilitiesRequest request) +0
   cswClient.csw.cswgetCapabilities(cswgetCapabilitiesRequest request) in d:\webapp\App_Code\ogc.csw.proxy.cs:12868
   cswClient.cswgetCapabilities(GetCapabilitiesType1 GetCapabilities) in d:\webapp\App_Code\ogc.csw.proxy.cs:12875
   tests_csw.Unnamed1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\webapp\tests\csw.aspx.cs:22
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3691
```

Comment: Is "LessThanOrEqualTo" meant to be a valid value?

Comment: Yes it should be. I guess something is wrong with the schema or data that's passing.

Comment: @John: you totally made me realize what the error was saying. place your comment as an answer and i'll give you the credit. (on monday, have a nice weekend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "LessThanOrEqualTo" meant to be a valid value? I think this message is saying that it tried to deserialize "LessThanOrEqualTo" as a value for the `ComparisonOperatorType` element (or attribute), but that the string "LessThanOrEqualTo" is not valid for the type of the element.